# How to use Arrays in Instance Methods?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, instance

```
  public class APPoint 
  { 
    private double myX; 
    private double myY; 

    public APPoint( double x, double y ) 
    { 
      myX = x; 
      myY = y; 
    } 

    public void move( double x, double y ) 
    { 
      myX += x; 
      myY += y; 
    } 

    public APPoint shiftCopy( double x, double y ) 
    {  
      return new APPoint( myX + x, myY + y ); 
    }


**My Code**

APPoint[] compassPoints = new APPoint{ I Don't know what to put here };
 return ??;





    public double getX()  
    { 
      return myX; 
    } 

    public void setX( double x ) 
    { 
      myX = x; 
    } 

    public double getY() 
    { 
      return myY; 
    } 

    public void setY( double y ) 
    { 
      myY = y; 
    } 
  } 
public static void main( String[] args )
{
  APPoint a = new APPoint( 1.0, 3.0 );
  APPoint b = a.shiftCopy( -2.0, 2.0 );
  APPoint c = a.shiftCopy( 3.0, 1.0 ).shiftCopy( 4.0, -5.0 );


}
```

My directions are to add an instance method called compassPoints that returns an array of four APPoint objects, each at distance 1 from the instance in the North,East, South, and West directions, then compassPoints should return an array of length 4 whose elements are the APPoint objects with he coordinates: (12.5, -7.1), (13.5, -8.1), (12.5, -9.1), and (11.5, -8.1).

If somebody could please help explain to me what I should put within the my code section, I'd be very grateful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
APPoint[] compassPoints = new APPoint[]{
    new APPoint(12.5, -7.1),
    new APPoint(13.5, -8.1),
    new APPoint(12.5, -9.1),
    new APPoint(11.5, -8.1) };
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
APPoint[] compassPoints = {
  new APPoint(12.5, -7.1),new APPoint(13.5, -8.1),
  new APPoint(12.5, -9.1),new APPoint(11.5, -8.1)
};
```

You can find other examples at [JLS-10.6 Array Initializers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6).